# Suggestion for a contact management database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I am currently designing a contact management database for a chamber of commerce. The goal of the database is to store all the **person** (except our own staff), all recorded **companies** (regular companies and member of the chamber), **addresses** of the person and companies, **tasks** that the staff are currently responsible for, a list of our staff (**user**) and the **roles** within the chamber.

---

### Business Rules

- one `person` works for one `company`
- one `company` have multiple `person`
- `person` and `company` can have multiple `address`
- one `company` can be in multiple `industry`
- one `industry` can have multiple `company`
- one `company` can have multiple `membertype`
- one `membertype` can have multiple `company`
- one `user` can play multiple `role`
- one `role` can be assigned to mutliple `user`
- one `user` can have multiple `task`
- one `task` can be worked on by multiple `user`
- one `task` can target multiple `person`
- one `person` can be targeted by multiple `task`
- one `person` can only be added by one `user`
- one `user` can add multiple `person`
- one `company` can have 0 or 1 `parent_company`
- one `parent_company` can have multiple child company

I have come up with the following design and it has undergone some changes:

### [image]

### Issue

- Are there better ways to display the `user-task-person` relationship?
- For example, if a `person` can have only one `email` but can have multiple `tel`, should I make an extra table just for `tel` while `email` is still in the `person`table? Would it considered to be "unclean"?
- For the table `membertype`, should `company_id` and `typename` both be PK?
- How does this schema look now? Are there still some normalisations to be done?

---

I'm a newbee at database, there are definitely some design flaws or errors, it would be nice if you guys could give me some suggestions so that I can correct and improve this design. Thank you ^~^

Comment: For efficiency in many:many mapping tables (of which you have several), see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: It is excessive to have many:many mapping for addresses.

Comment: You will need some secondary keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few misses.
First, the role table.  If one user can belong to more than one role, you're going to need another table between role and user.  1 table to store the roll(like you have already) and another to store a junction table which will store the relation between a role and a user.  That table would probably only have two columns, role_id and user_id.  The user table would not need to identify the role unless it was a primary role or default role.  That could also be accomplished in the junction table.

Similar situation with Company - Member Type.  Since you only have a single column in the company table, you will only be able to store one member type per company.  If the requirement is to have companies be able to be assigned to more than one member type, you will need a junction table to store company|member_type relationships.

One last thing I noticed, is there is currently no relation between Employee and Company other than the address.  That will definitely get confusing.
Since you want contacts to be associated with multiple companies, you will need another junction table to store the contact_id | company_id relationship. There might be a clever solution using your employee table.  Since that essentially is the only direct connection between employee and company, maybe just change that to the junction table, company_employee.  Then add a boolean/bit column (IsEmployee) to indicate whether the contact is actually an employee of the company.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! There's been some changes in business rules and the model. I've uploaded the latest version of the model (made using MySQL Workbench), would you care to take another look?

Comment: Hey @noobcoder.  I appreciate your question however as opposed to continually updating my answer as you update your requirements, I think some base reading should help you 'learn to fish' as it were.  I'm guessing you're not generally looking for me to design your application as you are looking for a way to design your own.  Anyways, here's some great reading that should get you started.
https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-11-database-third-normal-form-explained-in-simple-english/